# Split string with multiple delimiters stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split, delimiter

I have to split a string using multiple delimiters that are stored in a python dictionary.

For example, this is my dictionary with the delimiters:

```
import operator

ops = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv
}
```

And this is an example of string:

```
mystring = "2 * 3 + 4 + 5  / (9 + 5)"
```

The result should be:

```
result = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '(9', '5)']
```

It is possible to do this using only the variables 'mystring' and 'ops' and some function without hardcode all the delimiters strings as a function arguments?

Comment: As a starting point, you can collect keys using `ops.keys()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just split on any character that's not a number use:

```
import re
a = "(20 * 20 / 19 - 29) ** 2"
out_list = re.findall(r"[\d']+", a)
```

If you want to do the actual calculation then say:

```
eval("(20 * 20 / 19 - 29) ** 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegExp to solve this case for you.

```
r = re.compile('\(?\d+\)?')  # possible parenthesis surrounding an integer
r.findall(mystring)  

> ['2', '3', '4', '5', '(9', '5)']
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
import operator

ops = {"+": operator.add,
       "-": operator.sub,
       "*": operator.mul,
       "/": operator.truediv
       }

myString = "2 * 3 + 4 + 5 / (9 + 5)"


def getSubStrings(myInputString, delimiters):
    allSubStrings = [myInputString]

    tempList = []
    for eachKey in delimiters.keys():
        for eachSubString in allSubStrings:
            tempList += eachSubString.split(eachKey)
        allSubStrings = tempList
        tempList = []

    allSubStrings = [eachSubString.strip() for eachSubString in allSubStrings]

    return allSubStrings


print(getSubStrings(myString, ops))
```

and the answer for the given string is:

```
['2', '3', '4', '5', '(9', '5)']
```